# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#submit').click(function() {         

        jQuery("#LoadingImage").show();

        var imgSrc = 'http://foo.com/gen.php?username1=' + jQuery('input[name=username1]').val() + '&amp;username2='+ jQuery('input[name=username2]').val();

        jQuery('#imgRESULT').html('<img id="image1" src="' + imgSrc + '" >');
    });

    $('#image1').on("load", (function() {
        $("#LoadingImage").hide();
    });
});
```

With the html being

```
<div id="LoadingImage" style="display: none">
<img src.... /></div>​<div align="center" id="imgRESULT"></div>
```

and with the correct inputs etc.

But going into the console I get:

[image: error]

(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

I can't seem to see how to get this script working.
Any input?

Comment: Use a text editor that highlights your code to be able to spot your syntax errors quicker.

Comment: also Firebug is more informative about pointing out exact syntax errors

Answer (score 3):

```
                        V--------------extra parenthesis
$('#image1').on("load", (function() {
    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); }); <---extra parenthesis
});
```

Needs to be:

```
$('#image1').on("load", function() {
    $("#LoadingImage").hide();
});
```

You have an extra parenthesis before the function statement. Also switched out jQuery() to $() for appearances.

Comment: It does not matter whether jQuery or $ is is used, as long as jQuery is not running with noConflict.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have stated that, and thanks for the edits! It looks awesome. I will be more thorough next time